Gitlab gitlab-ci.yml specify network for build image
When you create your gitlab-ci.yml you specify an image that will be used to checkout your code and build it.  I was wondering if you can specify the docker/podman/container network to use for this container.

Why do you need special network settings here?  Ordinary docker build doesn't run connected to any particular network and can't normally interact with other containers (for good reason; when you push the built image it won't bring changes to other containers' state with it).

In my current situation. I have a integration test utilizing TestContainers.  I am using a hadoop HDFS image.  I need the test container to be able to talk with the hdfs container spawned from TestContainers
